# Multindex to one hot vector in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe like this

```
                    bill
    City   Month    
    3          01        14586
               02        14316
               03        17261
               04        16642
               05        14977
               06        14237
               07        14486
               08        14216
               09        17461
               10        16742
               11        14677
               12        14637

    4          01        24586
               02        24316
               03        27261
               04        26642
               05        24977
               06        24337
               07        24486
               08        24216
               09        27461
               10        26742
               11        24677
               12        24637
```

That I get from this line of code
`df = df.groupby(['City', 'Month']).sum()`

I'd like to get one hot encoding for `Month` index and convert it to 12 columns in order to have such a dataframe

```
     City   M1 M2 M3 ... M12   bill     
     3       1 0   0     0       46
     3       0 1   0     0       64
     3       0 0   1     0       386
    ...      
     4       1 0   0     0       546
     4       0 1   0     0       686 
    ...
```

Numbers don't match but I think idea is clear. My target is `bill` and
`Month` are features for ML model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and last for last column `bill` reaasign column by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Month'], prefix='M', prefix_sep='')
df['bill'] = df.pop('bill')
print (df)
  City  M01  M02  M03  M04  M05  M06   bill
0    3    1    0    0    0    0    0  14586
1    3    0    1    0    0    0    0  14316
2    3    0    0    1    0    0    0  17261
3    3    0    0    0    1    0    0  16642
4    3    0    0    0    0    1    0  14977
5    3    0    0    0    0    0    1  14337
```